# Change MenuItem style when IsCheckable=true and IsChecked=true

Tags: wpf, menuitem, mahapps.metro

Currently, when `IsChecked=true` MahApps shows a tick in the left side of `MenuItem`.

I want to change `MenuItem` style when `IsCheckable=True` and `IsChecked=true` without losing the default MahApps styles, alike *FullScreen* button on Visual Studio:

[image: Visual Studio Menu]

Is there a easy way to accomplish that?

Answer (score 1):

You could base your custom style on the MetroMenuItem style and set/override any property of the `MenuItem`:

```
<MenuItem Header="Item..." IsCheckable="True">
    <MenuItem.Style>
        <Style TargetType="{x:Type MenuItem}" BasedOn="{StaticResource MetroMenuItem}">
            <Style.Triggers>
                <MultiTrigger>
                    <MultiTrigger.Conditions>
                        <Condition Property="IsCheckable" Value="True" />
                        <Condition Property="IsChecked" Value="True" />
                    </MultiTrigger.Conditions>
                    <MultiTrigger.Setters>
                        <!-- set any properties you want here...-->
                        <Setter Property="FontSize" Value="30" />
                    </MultiTrigger.Setters>
                </MultiTrigger>
            </Style.Triggers>
        </Style>
    </MenuItem.Style>
</MenuItem>
```

Comment: With your snippet I can set the Border, however I can't remove the "tick" the MahApps adds by default when `IsChecked=true`

Comment: You need to set the Template property to your own custom ControlTemplate.